# Iphone custom cell keyboard overlaps

Tags: iphone, cell, textfield

i have a TableView with custom cells that i have built with Interface Builder.

Inside the cell, i have a label and a text field. But when i click on the text field to write, the keyboard overlaps the text field and i can't see what i am writing.

How can i avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to resize the view containing the tableview when keyboard is shown. The way you can do is discussed here,
[How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

You can search in Stackoverflow more on 'iphone keyboard hides textview'.

after resizing view, you can scroll table to the current cell too.